# How to configure Araxis merge with Git Extensions

Tags: git, merge, git-extensions, araxis-merge

How to configure Araxis merge/diff with Git Extensions?

I am trying to configure `Araxis merge` tool with `"Git Extensions"`, but found no help, all links or searches directs to Git only (using shell), Where as Git Extensions is GUI tool, it has an option (in **Global Settings** ) to configure different tools for `merge` and `diff` etc.

From **`difftool`** dropdown I select `Araxis`, it automatically selects the correct paths of installed locations

```
 C:/Program Files (x86)/Araxis/Araxis Merge/AraxisGitDiff.exe
```

From **`mergetool`** dropdown

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Araxis/Araxis Merge/AraxisGitMerge.exe
```

However each of them has an extra textbox with **difftool command** and **mergetool comand**, I have tried following commands in them

```
AraxisGitDiff.exe $1 $2
```

Keeping in mind that above command will substitute 1 and 2 what ever is selected from Git Extensions,
and when I right click on a file and sletect the option `"Open with difftool"` -> `"A <-> B "` nothing appears on the screen

Similalry making it

```
AraxisGitDiff.exe $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

does not work

I empty this filed I see following error.

```
---------------------------
Araxis Merge Command Line Compare Utility v7.0
---------------------------
Usage:

araxisgitdiff [/? | /h] <path> <old-file> <old-hex> <old-mode> <new-file> <new-hex> <new-mode>

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The settings I use are:

- `Mergetool` - Araxis
- `Path to mergetool` - `C:\Program Files\Araxis\Araxis Merge\Compare.exe`
- `Mergetool command` - `/merge /wait /a2 /3 "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"`
- `Difftool` - araxis
- `Path to difftool` - `C:\Program Files\Araxis\Araxis Merge\Compare.exe`
- `Difftool command` - LEAVE EMPTY

When merging, the left pane will be the local file and the right pane will be the remote file. The center pane contains the base file (or common ancestor) and you have to merge into this file/pane.

UPDATE - 2018-02-19

Seems that newer versions of GitExtensions may not work with the settings above. The changes below should fix any issues.

- `Mergetool` - Araxis
- `Path to mergetool` - `"C:\Program Files\Araxis\Araxis Merge\Compare.exe"`
- `Mergetool command` - `-merge -max -wait -a2 -3 "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"`
- `Difftool` - araxis
- `Path to difftool` - `"C:\Program Files\Araxis\Araxis Merge\Compare.exe"`
- `Difftool command` - `-max -2 -wait "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"`

Note that there are now double quotes around the path to the tools.

Comment: +1 that seems to work, I will try in detail for code file and will come back, thanks. at least instead of "nothing happens" its showing the diff tool and show the changes

Comment: this doesn't work any more (as of GitExtensions 2.48.05) for the diff tool.
I think it need a proper command instead of LEAVE EMPTY...?!

Answer (score 1):

The following steps have been tested with Git Extensions v2.47.3.

To use Araxis Merge for file comparison and file merging:

- In the Git Extensions browser, select Settings from the Tools menu.
- In the Settings window, select Global Settings from the tree on the left.
- In the Mergetool drop-down field, select Araxis.
- In the Path to mergetool field, enter the following:

  `C:/Program Files/Araxis/Araxis Merge/Compare.exe`
- In the Difftool drop-down field, select araxis.
- In the Path to difftool field, enter the following:

  `C:/Program Files/Araxis/Araxis Merge/Compare.exe`

[: Source](https://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-windows/integrating-with-other-applications#Git)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and managed to scratch out a workable solution by copying the pattern from kdiff3. This seems to work with Araxis 2010 and probably most subsequent versions

```
Mergetool
Araxis

Path to mergetool
C:/Program Files/Araxis/Araxis Merge/Merge.exe

Mergetool command
"C:/Program Files/Araxis/Araxis Merge/Merge.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED$"

Difftool
Araxis    

Path to difftool
C:/Program Files/Araxis/Araxis Merge/Merge.exe

Diftool command
"C:/Program Files/Araxis/Araxis Merge/Merge.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Wade answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52169805/1317546) I finally added Araxis folder (containing `Merge.exe`) to `PATH` then used this in my `.gitconfig` :

```
[diff]
    tool = araxis
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "araxis"]
    cmd = merge $LOCAL $REMOTE
```